# Same named variables into different structs

Tags: c, variables, struct, naming-conventions, variable-names

Is it possible to declare variables with the same name into different structs?
For example:

```
struct first
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int the_same;
};

struct second
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int the_same
};
```

Comment: Instead of asking here whether it's possible or not, why don't you _compile_ the code and see it for yourself?

Comment: I had already do, and it works, but I want some opinions, and I want to know if this method is advised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they work well as they belong to different [code scopes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29). You can access them by `first.the_same` and `second.the_same`.

> [...] Scope is an important component of name resolution, which is in turn fundamental to language semantics. Name resolution (including scope) varies between programming languages, and within a programming language, varies by type of entity. Together with namespaces, scoping rules are crucial in modular programming, so a change in one part of the program does not break an unrelated part. [...]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the variable with same name in different structure.

```
struct first
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int the_same;
};
```

Hear a,b and the_same are element of structure first. and in structure

```
struct second
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int the_same
};
```

x,y and the_same are element of structure second.

compiler will refer this variable with there structure name not individually..

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do so. You may have thought that It's like Enums which if you have same values in 2 different enums you'll get a compile time error but that would be possible if enums namespace differ. for example:

```
namespace a {
   enum a { a, b, c }

}

namespace b {
   enum a {a, b, c}
}
```

Comment: what is a namespace? I only know C and have never heard of such a thing.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. Namespaces are a feature added in C++. It's intention is to create new scopes in the code.

Comment: @NOVIN In C, the correct name for namespaces is *overloading classes*

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves As far as I know the concept of classes doesn't exist in C99 neither C11. And also in C++ namespaces have their own concept and as far as I know there's no such thing as overloading classes but "class operator(or function) overloading"

Comment: @Grady Player C has "_name spaces_".  See C11 `6.2.3 Name spaces of identifiers`.

Comment: @NOVIN As I said, the correct name is *overloading classes*, and if you don't believe me, you should read *C: A Reference Manual* (5th ed.), and have a look at Section 4.2.4. And no one talked about classes and C++, the fact that the word *class* shows up just got you confused ;)

Comment: @chux nice try at getting me on a technicality, but that is totally irrelevant.